# What is the theory for the quaternions?

Tags: logic, model-theory, quaternions

The axiomatic theory for the natural numbers is PA. For the reals it's RCF and for the complex numbers it's ACF. What's the theory for the quaternions?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that real closed fields is the axiomatic theory for the real numbers and that algebraically closed fields is the axiomatic theory for the complex numbers?

Comment: An axiomatic approach for the real numbers is given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number#Axiomatic_approach

Comment: There's a real sense in which your first statement is different from your second and third statements. By Gödel's theorem, PA is an incomplete theory, which means it axiomatizes *some* first-order truths about the natural numbers, but not all. On the other hand, RCF and ACF (actually ACF$_0$, the theory of algebraically closed fields of characteristic $0$) are complete. So while I would call RCF and ACF "the" theories of the real and complex numbers, I would call PA just "an" axiomatic theory for the natural numbers (if a particularly natural one).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Interesting - to me these statements about RCF and ACF$_0$ are uncontroversial, in contrast to the statement about PA.

Comment: See this MO question and its answers: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179640/are-the-quaternions-not-uncountably-categorical

Comment: I did not mention any controversy. I wrote what I wrote because the theory of Real Closed Fields applies to other fields other that the field of real numbers, and therefore I did not not understand in which sense that theory can be described as the axiomatic theory for the real numbers. A similar observation applies to complex numbers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Indeed the same is true for *any* first-order theory with infinite models, by the [Löwenheim-Skolem theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem). First-order logic is too weak to pin down any infinite structure uniquely up to isomorphism. But the fact that the theory RCF of real closed fields is complete means that every first-order sentence true of the real numbers is provable from RCF. To put it another way, all real closed fields satisfy exactly the same first-order sentences. The same is true for ACF$_0$ and algebraically closed fields.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thank you. I know that about ACF₀, but not about RCF.

Comment: @AlexKruckman thank you for the clarification about complete and incomplete theories, it is very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quaternions have the nice feature that we can recover the reals inside them in a definable way - in stark contrast to the situation with $\mathbb{C}$. Specifically, $\mathbb{R}$ sits inside $\mathbb{H}$ as the latter's **center**, the set of elements which (multiplicatively) commute with everything. Consequently the whole theory $Th(\mathbb{H})$ is generated by the (noncommutative unital) ring axioms, + $\mathsf{RCF}$ relativized to the center, + the existence of a triple of elements $i,j,k$ which multiply appropriately and together with $1$ span the whole ring over the center.

The proof that this works is similar to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4175105/proof-that-a-set-of-axioms-axiomatizes-the-complex-field-along-with-the-real-num?noredirect=1&lq=1) where the same idea develops a complete axiomatization for the field $\mathbb{C}$ *together with* a predicate naming $\mathbb{R}$. Note that per the first sentence of this answer, there's no model-theoretic difference between $\mathbb{H}$ and "$\mathbb{H}$-with-$\mathbb{R}$-labelled."