# An explicit recursive axiomatization of the nonnegative real numbers.

Tags: model-theory

Let $\mathbb{R}^+$ denote the nonnegative real numbers, and consider the structure $(\mathbb{R}^+;+,\cdot,0,1,\leq)$. Is there a recursive axiomatization of the complete theory of that structure, and if so, can someone exhibit such an axiomatization? Also, bonus question, can someone prove that there is no finite axiomatization of that theory, if indeed there isn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the nonnegative reals are bi-interpretable with the reals, the two structures have the same complexity in most senses of the word. In particular, the theory of the latter (RCF) is recursively axiomatizable but not finitely axiomatizable, and so the theory of the former is as well.

As to an explicit axiomatization, the above provides a recipe for doing this: let $\Phi$ be the obvious interpretation of $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}_{\ge}$, $\Psi$ the obvious interpretation in the other direction, and $\Theta$ the formula defining an isomorphism in $\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$ between $\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$ and $\Psi\Phi(\mathbb{R}_{\ge0})$. Then the following is an axiomatization for $\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$:

- the RCF axioms relativized to $\Phi$, and
- the statement that $\Theta$ gives an isomorphism between the domain and $\Psi\Phi$ of the domain.

Note that this is just a specific instance of the general strategy given in [a previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4168602/28111).